# how can I set the content of a html element via javascript (jquery) to php include file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

how can I set the content of a html element via javascript (jquery) to php include file
I mean something like

```
$('#loadTest').append(' <?php include_once "test.php"; ?>');
```

I also tried load

```
$('#loadTest').load('test.php',function(){
            alert("loaded!!")
        });
```

But it doesn't work :'(

Comment: Does test.php return html as output?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use AJAX:

```
$.get('test.php', function(data) {
    $('#loadTest').append(data);
});
```

The code has to be executed on the server, and the output is returned to you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer,I get the data but yet the loadTest content does not change :(

Comment: Does it look like this: `<div id="loadTest"></div>`?

Comment: Maybe try this just to test it: `$('#loadTest').html(data);`, using `html` instead of `append`.

Comment: Does it work if you put `alert(data);`? Maybe no data is coming through.

Comment: no, I really can not figure out what is the problem about the code